# WinRT app calling win32 c++ dll sending parameters

Tags: c#, c++, dll, windows-runtime, dllimport

Hey all this is the first time working with C++ so be kind :)

I have made a WinRT app that, since of some type of "sandbox" it does for those apps I am unable to access anything outside of that (like what I want to access - my desktop app.

So reading here and there I found out that if you make a C++ Dll and call it from the WinRT app then that would allow you to make calls outside of the "sandbox". But there's a little problem there.

I am currently getting an error of:

> Error CS1660  Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type.

Using this code here:

```
void Header_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayFromDLL("tester", s =>
    {
        // response is returned in s - do what you want with it
    });
}
```

The DisplayFromDLL is where its tossing that error from. More so the "s".

So the C# code I have to call the dll with looks like this:

```
public sealed partial class GroupedItemsPage : Page
{
    [DllImport("Win32Project1.dll", EntryPoint = "DisplayFromDLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void DisplayFromDLL(string name, String response);

    void Header_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayFromDLL("tester", s =>
        {
            // response is returned in s
        });
    }
```

And the C++ dll code:

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void DisplayFromDLL(const char name)
    {
        MessageBox("name is: " + name, "Msg title", MB_OK | MB_ICONQUESTION);
    }
}
```

So some help would be great to see what side is causing the error and what the situation fixing it might be.

Comment: Switching language while staying in the same process will not get you out of the sandbox, it would be to easy, wouldn't it? It seems you are using UWP ("Universal Windows Plaform"). WinRT is "just" an API. If you don't want the sandbox, don't use UWP, or develop another process outside the sandbox to talk with (with some mechanism)

Comment: So what would you suggest? Only reason I'm having to stay with WinRT is for the Metro Live Tiles. If I can get the same thing in WPF then that would solve this issue. I hear a lot about "Bridge" but not really understanding how that all works.

Comment: There's WinRT (the new Windows API), UWP the platform (xbox, devices, sandboxed, etc.) and the Packaging (msix, identity, used by sandbox). Some WinRT APIs are accessible to desktop apps, some are not. Some need a package identity, some don't. All this is currently moving, and the future is clearly WinUI3: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2020/05/19/introducing-winui-3-preview-1/ but right now, I believe you could indeed use live tiles API from a desktop app (maybe with packaging, I'm not sure): https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2018/11/02/xaml-islands-a-deep-dive-part-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think I found a good way to achieve my goal here.

I have added a simple, small Web Server in C# that WinRT can call. Doing this call allows me to run anything I need to *outside* the sandbox of the WinRT application.

This is the web server C# code (SimpleWebServer.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace smallWS
{
    public class WebServer
    {
        private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
        private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> _responderMethod;

        public WebServer(string[] prefixes, Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method)
        {
            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
                throw new NotSupportedException("Needs Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 or later.");

            if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

            if (method == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("method");

            foreach (string s in prefixes)
                _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);

            _responderMethod = method;
            _listener.Start();
        }

        public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method, params string[] prefixes)
            : this(prefixes, method) { }

        public void Run()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");
                try
                {
                    while (_listener.IsListening)
                    {
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
                        {
                            var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                            try
                            {
                                string rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                                byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                                ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                            }
                            catch { }
                            finally
                            {
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                            }
                        }, _listener.GetContext());
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            });
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _listener.Stop();
            _listener.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And also the Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace smallWS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, "http://localhost:8080/metroData/");
            ws.Run();
            Console.WriteLine("Webserver online. Press a key to quit.");

            Console.ReadKey();
            ws.Stop();
        }

        public static string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
        {
            Process.Start("C:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe");
            var dictionary = request.RawUrl.Replace("/metroData/", "").Replace("?", "").Split('&').ToDictionary(x => x.Split('=')[0], x => x.Split('=')[1]);
            return string.Format("<HTML><BODY>My web page.<br>{0}</BODY></HTML>", DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

And now GroupedItemsPage.xaml:

```
String mainURL = "http://localhost:8080/metroData/?";

async void Header_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var group = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(mainURL + "something=here&this=that"));
        string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your definition (in the DLL), the declaration (on the c# side) and the actual calls do not match at all.

Your function as defined takes a single char, your declaration says it takes two strings, but your call provides a string and a function.

Make it so that all of these match.

Answer (score 0):

If the limitations of the UWP sandbox get in the way of your design, **develop a desktop application**. For the platform that's closest to UWP in terms of UI design, go for WPF. You can still publish it to the store, via the Desktop Bridge.

Comment: Correct but the overall point being that I need the Metro Tiles as the UI and that does not seem to work in anything other than a WinRT app.

Comment: Never tried, but [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/secondary-tiles-desktop-pinning) suggests you can publish tiles from desktop apps.